# How to place objects of variable dimensions into an array in R?

Tags: arrays, r, multidimensional-array

I have an array that is 3 dimensional.  In each cell of the array, I need to fill it in with a list, (or another array, or matrix, just needs to be a series of values).  However, each of  the lists/arrays to be stored in said cells are of different sizes.

Here's how  I create the array:

`ar <- array(0, c(365, 6, 4))`

`ar[3,2,1]=list(3,2,4,5,3,2)  # throws error`

```
> ar[3,2,1]=array(3,c(1,2))
Error in ar[3, 2, 1] = array(3, c(1, 2)) : 
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

It also doesn't work If I try to initialize the array with empty arrays, empty lists or NA instead of zero values.

Any easy way around this problem?  these objects in the 3-D array must be easily indexable.  Thanks.

Comment: Compare `dim(ar)` and `length(list(3,2,4,5,3,2))`.

Comment: The result is 365, 6, and 4,......and .....6, respectively.  Not sure I understand, what additional information is this?        Remember that I am trying to fill each **cell** of the multi-dimensional array (365 by 4 by 5) with another array.  And each of those cells will be filled with arrays of varying sizes.

Comment: You want to fill 8760 cells with 6 values? Also, `ar[3,2,1]` is one value. You probably want `ar` to be a `list`, not an `array`.

Comment: `array` is a n-dimensional "matrix". You cannot insert lists into it, per se.

Comment: So,  seems like there is no friendly solution?  @Pascal, like I said in my question: "It also doesn't work If I try to initialize the array with empty arrays, empty lists or NA instead of zero values".

Answer (score 0):

This seems unwieldy to me, but I think it's what you're asking for:

```
ar <- array(list(), dim=c(5, 3, 2))
ar[1, 1, 1] <- list(list(1, 2, 3, 4, 5))
ar[2, 1, 1] <- list(matrix(seq(4), nrow=2))
ar[3, 1, 1] <- "foo"
ar[4, 1, 1] <- list(array(-1, dim=c(5, 7, 9)))
ar
# , , 1
# 
#      [,1]        [,2] [,3]
# [1,] List,5      NULL NULL
# [2,] Integer,4   NULL NULL
# [3,] "foo"       NULL NULL
# [4,] Numeric,315 NULL NULL
# [5,] NULL        NULL NULL
# 
# , , 2
# 
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,] NULL NULL NULL
# [2,] NULL NULL NULL
# [3,] NULL NULL NULL
# [4,] NULL NULL NULL
# [5,] NULL NULL NULL
```

Note the need to wrap cell contents longer than length=1 in an extra `list()` when assigning them.